# Access violation on WinInetHttpInfo.QueryInfo

Tags: web-services, delphi, cookies

I got a simpel question. Does anybody know how I can retrieve the cookies from a webservice in Delphi?
I've already tried the following code and I can read all data from the soap header but the cookies are missing and I know they are there because when I call a function from the webservice by SoapUI I can see them.
I made a simpel form an put a button on it. On click of the button event calls a function with the following instructions in it:

Any idea?

```
var
  hInet: HINTERNET;
  hConnect: HINTERNET;
  infoBuffer: array [0..INTERNET_MAX_PATH_LENGTH] of char;
  dummy: DWORD;
  bufLen: DWORD;
  okay: LongBool;
  reply: String;
begin
  hInet := InternetOpen(PChar(application.title),             INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG_WITH_NO_AUTOPROXY, nil, nil, 0);
  hConnect := InternetOpenUrl(hInet, PChar(url), nil, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_NO_UI, 0);
  if not Assigned(hConnect) then
    result := false
  else
  begin
    dummy := 0;
    bufLen := Length(infoBuffer);
    okey := HttpQueryInfo(hConnect, HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF, @infoBuffer[0], bufLen, dummy);
    ...
```

I also have a HTTPRIO component on my form which I use to communicate with the webservice. What I couldn't figure out is how I can use this component to get it work with the code above.

Thank you all in advance for your answer,

Farshid

Comment: What exactly is the question? The subject seems unrelated to the body.

Comment: If you want to use the HTTPRIO component, you don't need to open a HINTERNET etc. manually. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

When calling HttpQueryInfo(), the buffer size needs to be expressed in **bytes**, but you are expressing it in **characters** instead.  If you are using Delphi 2009 or later (you did not say which you are using), then `SizeOf(Char)` is 2, not 1.

Try this:

```
bufLen := Length(infoBuffer) * SizeOf(Char);
okey := HttpQueryInfo(hConnect, HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF, @infoBuffer[0], bufLen, dummy);
...
```

Or:

```
bufLen := SizeOf(infoBuffer);
okey := HttpQueryInfo(hConnect, HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF, @infoBuffer[0], bufLen, dummy);
...
```

That being said, you can alternatively ask `HttpQueryInfo()` for the necessary byte size instead:

```
var
  infoBuffer: array of Byte;
...
bufLen := 0;
okey := HttpQueryInfo(hConnect, HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF, nil, bufLen, dummy);
if (not okey) and (GetLastError = ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) then
begin
  SetLength(infoBuffer, bufLen);
  okey := HttpQueryInfo(hConnect, HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF, Pointer(infoBuffer), bufLen, dummy);
end;
if okey then
begin
  // use PChar(infoBuffer) up to (Length(infoBuffer) div SizeOf(Char)) characters...
  ...
end;
```